# Find folder in GDrive that not contain a file

Tags: google-drive

I have a well-structured dataset stored in GDrive, in the root folder, I have the days subfolder named in the format YYYYMMDD, and in each subfolder some CSV file with the data.

Can you suggest me a way to find all subfolders that do **NOT** contains a file?

Thanks